# How to format and compare input from a bash/vm?

Tags: java, bash, file, input, output

I'm working on a Desktop Application which will analyze some stuff on a virtual machine. 
I get to write and read after the `SSH` connection. 
I save the input in a temporary `.txt` file. Now I want to compare it to let's say another `.txt` file which contains the correct `amount/name` of directories.
For example if I want to check for the directories on `../workspace/` with my below code from `scanForVm`. The content (actually not only the command output) is saved to a `.txt` file.

I have the problem that it writes some unnecessary stuff into it and I'm unable to compare it with my other `.txt` file.

I tried to search for an answer for several hours now and tried different approaches.

```
public void scanForVm(MouseEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (event.getSource() == scanButton) {

        networkCheck.scanNetwork();
        sshConnection.connectionToSsh("ls -d workspace/*/\n");
        sshConnection.readOutput();
    }

}
```

and then:

```
public void readOutput() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Path file = Paths.get(" / path / To / Text.txt ");

    System.out.println(outputDescr); //Debug format
    InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    String output = "";

    while ((read = stdout.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, read);
        Files.write(file, buffer);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

I want the input from the vm to be actual readable.

Now I get this:

Identity added:

```
/path/path/path/.ssh/...
[0m[01;36mworkspace/directory/[0m                 [01;36mworkspace/directory2/[0m  
ls -d workspace/*/
```

And I want it to be only:

```
workspace/directory/
workspace/directory2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0m` and `[01;36m` are colour identifiers. `[0m` signifies no colour, `[01;36m` signifies light cyan. They could be parsed out using a regex like `\[(0|\d+;\d+)m`.

In your specific example, everything that starts out setting the colour to light cyan and back to Standard at the end could be found using `\[01;36m(.+?)\[0m` with group 1 containing the desired string. You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/A906Na/1